# "Rage Quit" what is it?

Tags: slang, terminology

I often hear the younger population using the term "rage quit". Could someone let me know if any of the following uses of this term are correct:

> I was so rage quit

Or

> he was feeling rage quitted

Comment: It means to *quit in a rage*. Something in the game (or whatever you're doing) pisses you off so much, you quit or leave on the spot.

Comment: Is your question about the meaning of the phrase, or how to use it grammatically?

Comment: Rage is describing the verb 'quit' in this case, so the grammar for it would be "I was so angry I rage quit."   I've also seen it made into one word: "ragequit" which is used as a verb.  Quitted is acceptable, but not used often: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=past%20tense%20of%20quit

Comment: Search for: **urban dictionary rage quit** Again, if you can't find a phrase in a dictionary such as Webster or Oxford, try the Urban Dictionary.

Comment: As @ColleenV asks, are you asking *What is it?* (your question title)  or *How to use it?*

Comment: I think it's better to let the OP edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's slang to begin with, it's difficult to entirely rule out *any* usage. But in general, no, "rage quit" is a (phrasal) verb with an implied object of "the game" (or whatever else is in context), so those usages don't work well when switching the object back to the subject reflexively. In other words, one can rage quit a game, or more rarely rage quit anything one is doing, but oneself is in no sense rage quit. Even in the rare case of someone else rage quitting you (an odd way to describe the result of a date gone horribly wrong?), it would seem unnatural.

Anecdotally, I've never seen anything like the examples while playing several MMOs.

Comment: Likewise, I've never seen rage quit used the way it is in the examples, and I spend a lot of my free time in online games. Apparently the new phrase is "getting salty", but being the old fart  I am, I ignore general chat most of the time. "I am so rage quit" could be used in genres I don't play (Anime style stuff, for example). I've found different genres have different dialects similar to the way different regions in the same country might.

Answer (score 0):

It's a term that's commonly used in the gaming community.  It refers to when someone quits a game because they are frustrated.

It can also be used to refer to similar situations that don't necessarily pertain to gaming.